# Auto resize large text editor height based on data in AG Grid angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid-angular

I have a large-text-editor column in AG Grid.How can I auto resize editor element height in each row based on content.

The text editor/cell editor should open up with a height based on the different data from api for a particular column.